# How to create and add a Java class in an APK using Soot?

Tags: java, android, android-instrumentation, soot

I want to instrument an APK to count the number of executions of its callback methods (similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950888/instrumenting-android-apps-with-soot-using-a-helper-class/24190528#24190528)).

To do so, I want to create a static class from scratch (similar to this [link](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Creating-a-class-from-scratch)) which keeps the counting numbers. Then add this class to the APK, and finally instrument the beginning of callback methods to call a method of this static class (similar to this [link](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Instrumenting-Android-Apps-with-Soot)).

I was able to do a similar thing with a Java application but I couldn't do it for an APK. Here is the part of the code that generates a new SootClass and adds it to `Scene`:

```
SootClass staticCls = generateClass("StaticCounter");
Scene.v().addClass(staticCls);
Scene.v().addBasicClass("StaticCounter", SootClass.SIGNATURES);
Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
```

`generateClass` is adapted from [here](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Creating-a-class-from-scratch). But when I examined the modified APK, there was no sign of `StaticCounter` class. Moreover, I installed and ran the modified APK and got this error:

```
08-21 14:15:45.936 19917 19917 E AndroidRuntime:
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  Didn't find class "StaticCounter" on path:
   DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/APKNAME-RdhHiJzxKyyUHh_KCi6RUA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/APKNAME-RdhHiJzxKyyUHh_KCi6RUA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

Which simply shows the generated class is not inside the APK.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found why the newly generated class was unknown to the app thanks to [Martin Zitler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599486/2681272)'s hint. The generated class must be in the package of the APK. Soot handles the package of a class by looking at the signatures of the class. As a result, the `StaticCounter` class must have a signature like

```
com.example.app.StaticCounter
```

which indicates that `StaticCounter` is in the package `com.example.app`.

It is possible to find the package name using `ProcessManifest` class which can be found in FlowDroid:

```
new ProcessManifest(apkPath).getPackageName();
```

I simplified the working code and put it [here](https://gist.github.com/noidsirius/1ba0493694e79299b74994c8ac70dfb1). It creates a new class from scratch and adds a static integer field and a method that the field is the times that the static method is called, and the method prints this value. Then using a transformation pack, every method in the app will call this static method.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to provide the dependency it demands:

```
android {
    useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"
}
```

The reason why it won't build might be, that `StaticCounter` is unknown at compile time - because it likely should **not** be referenced from within the application package, which does not know it. Check out this [blog post](https://www.bodden.de/2013/01/08/soot-android-instrumentation/), apparently from the `Soot` author... the driver class might be key to success:

```
//prefer Android APK files// -src-prec apk
Options.v().set_src_prec(Options.src_prec_apk);

//output as APK, too//-f J
Options.v().set_output_format(Options.output_format_dex);

// resolve the PrintStream and System soot-classes
Scene.v().addBasicClass("java.io.PrintStream", SootClass.SIGNATURES);
Scene.v().addBasicClass("java.lang.System", SootClass.SIGNATURES);
```

here's the whole example: [AndroidInstrument.java](http://www.bodden.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/AndroidInstrument.java_.txt)

Comment: Thanks. But I've already followed the steps from the blog post. It works fine when there is no extra class: after running the app, it will print a log whenever I perform one of the callbacks. However, I'm interested to add a new class (`StaticCounter`) to the package. I think there should be a way to change the configurations of APK itself to let the newly introduced class will be visible for all the methods.

Comment: @noidsirius you could possibly add it into the test-application by adding it into the `androidTest` source-set, or use a `TestSuite` and add it into there... `Soot` seems rather specialized for desktop Java, which is a whole other animal - and therefore there might be certain limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Soot will not emit the class unless you have flagged it as application class. Can you try that?

Comment: I did that, thanks though. It seems the problem was because of the package of the class.